# Microservice architecture dvd rental application

Tags: java, spring-boot, service, architecture

I have a simple Data model as below. I am creating microsevices for these tables. What is the best approach to create microservices, do I need to create one microservice per table ?

[database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVg15.png)

Answer (score 0):

microservices should be created based on service basis, not per table basis. You should create separate microservice for payment, rental, inventory, customer.